# Convert Facebook API batch request into FQL multiquery

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My web app builds a batch request to the Facebook graph API. The batch is composed by making a first API call to grab the user's friends. Then I loop over the list of friends and add a specific request for each (with that user's specific access token) and add each one to the batch. So it ends up being two API calls. Unfortunately, it's REALLY slow, and I've heard the FQL requests are faster.

So my question is, can I do this with FQL? I've read [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) but I can't figure out how I might return, for example, all the friends of friends' work history (which requires each friend's access token) with one single FQL query. Is this possible? Obviously I could build a batch request of FQL requests, but that would leave me back where I started.

**UPDATE:**
I've done some tests and FQL definitely seems to be faster than a batch request. My FQL multiquery looks like this:

```
$multiQuery = array(
"query1"=>"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()", //LIST OF FRIEND IDs
"query2"=>"SELECT uid, name, work, education, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query1)", //FRIEND PROFILES
"query3"=>"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid FROM #query2 WHERE is_app_user=1)",
"query4"=>"SELECT uid, name, work, education FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query3)"
);

$multiQueryResult = $facebook->api(array(
'method'   => 'fql.multiquery',
'queries'  => $multiQuery
));

var_dump( $multiQueryResult );
```

The query works but there are two problems:

1. query3 returns all the user ids, NOT just the ones who've authorized
   my app.
2. query4 doesn't return the work/education fields... presumably
   because the API request is being called with the current user's
   access token (as opposed to that of specific user from query3). I've stored the authorized users' access tokens in the DB, but I don't know if it's possible to use them in this context.

CAN this be done with FQL?? Can I define unique access tokens within an FQL multiquery?

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'm trying to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to my original question because there doesn't appear to be one. It seems that at the time of writing this, the Facebook batch request is just really slow... which is too bad since that basically defeats its entire purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> all the friends of friends' work history (which requires each friend's access token)

If you need different access tokens, then obviously there’s no way of doing it in one single request … but where would you get each of my friends access tokens anyway, if they wouldn’t have interacted with your app themselves recently? And if they would have, you could’ve gotten their work info then already and put it into your own database, so that you could get it from there just using the uids of my friends for lookup. Otherwise, I think this is *not* really your way to go.

It’d rather be this way:

If friends of your user have set up their privacy settings so that they are willing to share their work info with apps your user is using, then you can get that info without requiring an individual access token for each one of those friends. Then you would just do an FQL query like this,

```
SELECT uid, name, work FROM user WHERE uid IN
  (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me())
```

That’ll give you your user’s friends work info – but obviously only for those that are willing to share that info with apps a friend is using.

Comment: I have stored their access tokens in my DB. The point of this app is to find connections between "friends of friends". So for example, the current user searches for information in the profile of any of their friends, or anyone THEIR friends know (who have already authorized the app).

Comment: I'm hoping FQL multiquery might let me do what I'm trying to do. I've updated my question to show my current direction of thought. Any chance this will work?

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tested my original code with batched FQL queries and it's just as slow as batched graph requests. So the "batch" seems to be the source of the problem. The final question is whether there is any other way to do what I'm trying to do.